# How I can know the limit for groups read?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-groups

I'm working into the migration of a large list to Google Groups from Google Apps Script.

After some creation of members, i'm having this Exception:

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium groups
> read.

There is one way to know the available quote of reads for integrate this verification into my code.

This is my function:

```
function readSheet(){
    var sheetId='MY-ID';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    var toIgnore = 1;
    var mData = sheet.getDataRange().offset(toIgnore, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - toIgnore).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < mData.length; i++) {
        /*Here verify quota*/
        addUsertoGroup(mData[i][0]);
    }
}
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your script reaches a quota or limitation.

You can see the daily quotas for `Groups read` in the [table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#g_suite) below:

[image]

You can use a try..catch statement to ignore the error:

```
function readSheet(){
    var sheetId='MY-ID';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    var toIgnore = 1;
    var mData = sheet.getDataRange().offset(toIgnore, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - toIgnore).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < mData.length; i++) {
      try{
        addUsertoGroup(mData[i][0]);
      }
      catch(e){
        console.log("The script reached the daily quota: ",e);
      }
}
}
```

Comment: I think Google is applying the 2,000 quota limit, but my plan is Workspace Basic (actually in 14 days trial). Do you know how i can check my real quota limit? For this link, my quota is 10,000 reads, but the insertion was stoped about the row 1,700 .

Comment: @A.Cedano I think you might be able to see it [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits). I am not admin myself nor do I have access to this info. I also believe that other simultaneous requests (also by other users) like writing might be part of this quota. Also, if you are not admin, there is a chance that you are given less quota than the maximum.

Comment: The issue is not with Sheets, but inserting members into Google Groups. If I comment the function call into the loop `//addUsertoGroup(mData[i][0]);` I can read all rows into the Sheet. I think the issue is with this code: `var mStatus=AdminDirectory.Members.insert(newMember, groupId);`. I'm Admin and not are another users into my WorkSpace. I execute some tests today, but not 10,000 or 5,000 reads.

Comment: @A.Cedano there are limitations for adding people to groups and different limitation for adding external people to groups. Please see this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/w5qa13) which can also be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6099642?fbclid=IwAR23iNzClFIdQ7nuteoKk3TVOf1YoIUBE2xvy455wS7rR3qhoVx-_XhQqr0) and let me know if you think you exceeded these numbers.

Comment: @A.Cedano there are also specific limits for trial accounts. You can find it in the same link in my previous comment or see [this](http://prntscr.com/w5qbqh) screenshot.

Comment: I don't know really. The first time I ran the script I added about 1,700 external members into one group (Google Groups), and after that, the Exception appeared... Three hours later I tried to continue inserting members into the group, I can insert 10 new members and then the Exception occurred again.

Comment: I guess for now you can use the code snippet I provided and check what is maximum `i` it fails. @A.Cedano

Comment: It fails at first time now, i will try tomorrow with the new daily quota. Thanks for your help and for the links you provided me. I will back when i will have quota.